# How to use method that is not included in abstract class

Tags: c++

For example, if I have an abstract class I_Student that has only 2 virtual functions:

- `void set() = 0`
- `void print() = 0`

And a derived class Student that contains other functions.

If I declare pointer that is type I_Student*, that points to a Student object

```
I_Student* s = new Student();
```

How can I call methods via pointer s without making them pure virtual in I_Student ?

Comment: ***can I use methods via I_Student from Student without making prototypes that are virtual in I_Student ?*** Yes you can do that. You only want to make them virtual if you plan to implement the function in the derrived class

Comment: The short answer is no but there are mechanisms to deal with such use cases. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+derived+class+function+from+base+class+object.

Comment: @drescherjm FWIW I read *can I use methods via I_Student from Student without making prototypes that are virtual in I_Student* is can the call the derived class function from the base class pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm Please show me an example

Comment: I read it as can I call functions in the base class from the derrived class that are not marked virtual in the base.

Comment: ***Please show me an example*** It's no different from calling a function in the same class (well except if it was private in the base). Although the other two posters believe I am reading the question wrongly..  I may be. You may need to add some code context to better explain the problem.

Comment: C++ does not have a concept of "prototypes". That's a C thing. What does your question actually mean?

Comment: @melpomene I mean't without overriding virtual function

Comment: Please make something of a [mcve]. OK, there is no problem you can demonstrate. But please provide all class definitions, introduce variables of those class types, maybe a pointer to an instance and then write show some explanation/pseudo code, commented code or even compiler-error-provoking code to just help to understand what you want to do. Maybe "class def, variable def, pointer to base class def, point to derived class, call via pointer". Without more info about what you try to do, answering ends up in guessing...

Comment: Please add a minimal example of what your problem is.

Comment: With the `s` pointer you can call any public function  that exists in the base class `I_Student` virtual or not. If you are trying to call member functions of `Student` then I got the question wrong.

Comment: Please read up on XY problems. I think we might be looking at one. Please explain what you want to achieve, either in much more concrete detail or, better, in an abstract way. Not "How can I do this? (while I actually think it is the way to that)", instead "How can I do that? I do not care how exactly.".

Comment: To elaborate on Yunnosch's comment, why do you have these two particular classes, and why can't you change `I_Student` (weird naming convention btw) to suit your needs?

Comment: @SebastianRedl (I_)Student  stands for interface since c++ does not have Interface classes, its easier to distinct abstract classes from non abstract ones

Comment: @Finixzz Common conventions are to prefix interfaces with just `I`, no underscore (.Net, Windows COM), or to not have a prefix at all (Java). Having mixed case and underscores in a single convention is very unusual.

Comment: @SebastianRedl In C++ `I_` is a convention that is seen somewhat often. Anyway that's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Considering:

- `Base` being `I_Student`
- `Derived` being `Student`

Yes, you can call a method of `Derived` class with a pointer of type `Base*` (Which actually points to a `Derived` instance). So you can always cast the other way.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
     void Foo()     { std::cout << "Foo is called\n"; }
     void Bar()     { std::cout << "Bar is called\n"; }
     void FooBar()  { std::cout << "FooBar is called\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // Example 1 (Assume that basePtr is pointing to a Derived instance)
    {
        Base* basePtr = new Derived;
        static_cast<Derived*>(basePtr)->FooBar();
        delete basePtr;
    }

    // Example 2 (Verify that basePtr is pointing to a Derived instance)
    {
        Base* basePtr = new Derived;
        if (Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePtr))
        {
            derived->FooBar();
        }
        delete basePtr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Call me a purist, but if I end up casting anything, then I start looking for the mistake in my class and interface design... (Downvote not by me though.)

Comment: The OP asked if there is a way to do this kind of thing, I provided a way (And the only one). So yes, avoid casting when possible, but the question isn't "Should I cast?".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I disagree. `dynamic_cast` brings a runtime overhead, while `reinterpret_cast` doesn't. In our case, we are sure that `basePtr` is pointing to a `Derived` instance, so the runtime check is avoidable

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is still wrong. If you don't want a runtime check, you should use `static_cast`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My bad, I thought you couldn't downcast with a static_cast

Comment: @AdrienGivry Thank's a lot ! You hit the spot!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to access methods of a derived class `Student` from a `I_Student*`, except by casting first to a `Student`.

```
Student* s2 = dynamic_cast<Student*>(s);
if (s2 != nullptr)
  ...
```

Comment: If you expect `s` to be of type `Student*` you could also `dynamic_cast<Student&>(*s)` and omit the `nullptr` check.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function of the derived or Students Class through `I_student` class just by making function a virtual function. Once a function is made virtual now whenever it is called , it will be called on the basis on the reference of object calling it. In this case the pointer 's' is of type `I_students`, but it has the reference of its parent . So that is how the Student's function will be called.
I have shown it here

```
class I_Students
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Im I_student"<<endl;
    }
};

class Students :public I_Students
{
public:
    virtual void print()
    {
        cout << "Im student" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    I_Students *s = new Students;
    s->print();
}
```